# Is the given statement regarding Radial Probability Distribution Function correct or not?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

> Radial Distribution Function $(4πr^2R^2(r))$ gives the probability of the electron being present at a distance $r$ from the nucleus.

**Answer:** The given statement is correct.

**My Query:**
According to me, isn't the Radial Probability Distribution Function ($RPDF$) used for finding the probability of an electron being present at a distance $r$ from the nucleus ***within a region of thickness  $dr$***?

Therefore, shouldn't the above statement be wrong?

Comment: The emphasized part is implicitly assumed. Anyway, the probability to be _exactly_ at a distance $r$ is $0$.

Comment: You are correct it should be $r \to r+dr$ but it is not often written that way.

Comment: @IvanNeretin are you saying that both answers are correct?

Comment: @porphyrin so then mine is correct too, right?

Answer (score 7):

Conceptually you are right as the commenters have mentioned, but since we are on a thread about nitpicking, we might as well go the extra distance.

Technically, $r^2R^2$ itself is not a probability but a **probability density**. In order to get the actual *probability*, you need to integrate it over a region. The *probability* of finding an electron between $r = r_1$ and $r = r_2$ would therefore be

$$P = \int_{r_1}^{r_2}r^2R^2 \, \mathrm dr \tag{1}$$

For an infinitesimal region, it suffices to multiply by $\mathrm dr$, such that the infinitesimal *probability* of finding an electron in the region $(r, r + \mathrm dr)$ is

$$\mathrm dP = r^2R^2 \,\mathrm dr \tag{2}$$

Notice how if you integrate $(2)$ over a finite region you get $(1)$.

Also, some books give this extra factor of $4\pi$, which I never really understood. You have two choices: either the probability density function is $r^2R^2$ (which works for all orbitals), or $4\pi r^2\psi^2$ (which works only for spherically symmetric orbitals, i.e. s-orbitals). I've written about this in more detail at  [What is the exact definition of the radial distribution function?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/107097/16683), so won't repeat myself here.

Comment: I've read your answer before posting this question, and thanks a lot1